# Installing libraries in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup uWSGI for nginx on a default Amazon AMI Linux instance.

To do that, I need to install these libraries: libxml2-dev python2.6-dev python-libxml2

However, when I try a yum install, I get this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
amzn                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                    | 1.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge/primary                            | 2.2 MB     00:01     
rpmforge                                               10349/10349
Setting up Install Process
No package libxml2-dev available.
No package python2.6-dev available.
No package python-libxml2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How do I proceed?

I installed rpmforge myself, but I don't know what other repos I can install that have these packages (I'm a linux noob)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the packages have different names on EC2-Linux? You could search with yum for parts of the name to find the right ones: `yum search libxml` or `yum search python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ubuntu or Debian. They are much easier(libxml2-dev python2.6-dev python-libxml2 are Debian packages)

In CentOS install python26-devel(EPEL) and libxml2-devel.